# Layout hides if keyboard is displayed

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a layout for a fragment which contains EditText box and one Recyclerview.whenever i click on edidtext box for inputting, whole layout disappears and when i press back button, keyboard hides and layout is again displayed.

Comment: can you post screenshots and code??

Answer (score 1):

You have to switch your activity's windowSoftInputMode flag to "adjustPan". Check [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) for further reference.

```
<activity
   ...
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"> 
</activity>
```

Hope it works for you.